# The server at www.facebook.com100003773239192%26photoid%3D can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-applications, facebook-php-sdk

```
//Create an album
$album_details = array(
        'message'=> 'How will you die?',
        'name'=> 'How will you die?'
);
$create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);


//Get album ID of the album you've just created
$album_uid = $create_album['id'];

//Upload a photo to album of ID...

$file='img/'.$fbid.'.jpg'; //Example image file

$photo_details = array( 'message'=> 'Find...51', 'image' => '@'.realpath($file));

 if ($session) {
    // We have a valid FB session, so we can use 'me'
    $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
} elseif( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {
    $upload_photo = $facebook->api("/{$_SESSION['user_id']}/photos", 'post', $photo_details);
}

$upphoto = $upload_photo['id'];


ImageDestroy( $canvas );

header("Location: http://www.facebook.com".$fbid."&photoid=".$upphoto."")
```

I have created a facebook application which uploads photo users wall.

But repeatedly i am getting the above error. I guess that '`/`' is missing somewhere in the above piece of code, But i don't know where to put '`/`'. If any other mistakes are caught then please help me in making this code complete and working.

Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
header("Location: http://www.facebook.com".$fbid."&photoid=".$upphoto."")
```

to

```
header("Location: http://www.facebook.com/".$fbid."&photoid=".$upphoto);
```

Comment: Pretty sure you also don't need the `.""` after `$upphoto`.

Comment: Even better is to write `header("Location: http://www.facebook.com/" . urlencode($fbid) . "&photoid=" . urlencode($upphoto));` (I don't know why you think there needs to be a `.""` at the end, Mark?)

Comment: I replaced the code as per ur comment @Daan but i am getting another error thats is 'The page you requested was not found. and get this URL in the address bar 'http://www.facebook.com/100003773239192&photoid=' . Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: I don't know what your URL is supposed to look like, but that also seems to indicate that `$upphoto` is empty. Try `print_r` to see whether that variable is actually set correctly. (And sorry Mark, I must've misread - I thought you said "also need" rather than "also don't need")